# Why doesn't the Software Center resume downloading packages when it is interrupted?

Tags: software-center, downloads

I wonder if there is a tool that can resume broken downloads when the Ubuntu Software Center is downloading packages for software it features or shows.

For example I was downloading `skype` and by the time I had downloaded 12MB, the net link broke. Again I went to the Software Center and then began downloading `skype` from the start. So is there anything which can resume downloads that are interrupted?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a problem limited to the Software Center - command-line package managers support resuming interrupted downloads.

To install Skype via the command-line, open a terminal and type:

> `sudo apt-get install skype`

*Note: this assumes you have enabled the Canonical Partner Repository from within the Software Center.*

Now if anything happens to your connection and it somehow gets interrupted - just rerun that command and it will continue downloading from where it left off.